# creating a list comprehension for my function

Tags: python-3.x

I have a function that basically does a Fibonacci except mine is that it will accept first a 3 digits/element in a list (signature) add those so that the sum is its fourth element. Then get the next 3 digit then sum it up to be its 5th element in a list. THe normal FOR loop works fine However I am trying to do it using list comprehension but it keeps failing for me.

The list comprehension below doesnt work for me.

```
def tribonacci3(signature, n):
    return [(signature[i-1] + signature[i-2] + signature[i-3]) for i in range(3,n)][:n]
```

Below is the working code for the FOR loop.

```
def tribonacci2(signature, n):
    for i in range(3, n): 
        signature.append(signature[i-1] + signature[i-2] + signature[i-3])
    print(signature)
    return signature[:n]
```

If I use the list comprehension I made the result shows an empty list.

Comment: The for loop modifies `signature` in place and the references it during the next iteration.  That is not compatible with a comprehension.

Comment: The real question is *why* you would want to use list comprehension in the first place.  Personally, I find it very confusing and I prefer using traditional for loops.  Also, the code compiles almost identically, so there isn't a performance boost (as far as I know).

Comment: To answer your question Caleb, I am trying to practice on how to use list comprehension. So everytime I would get a FOR loop i would try to convert it. This one is where Im confused though.